# Null spaces and their dimensions. how to decide the dimension of the null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is a quote from a textbook.

> Within four dimensional space ofa ll possible vectors x the solutions to $$Ax=0$$ form a two dimensional subspace - the nullspace of A

In this specific A we found

$$(-3,1,0,0)$$
$$(1,0,-1,1)$$

My question is how come such special vectors form a two dimensional subspace.

Two dimensional subspace is a plane right?
Shouldn't it form a two dimensional subspace when A is in $$R^{3}$$

Or how am i going to decide that subspace of two specific vectors and their scalars and their sums etc etc form what direction? how am i going to decide that is there any way or something like that?

Comment: So long as the vectors are linearly dependent, each "adds" a dimension.  So a nullspace of dimension one is a line, a nullspace of dimension 2 is a plane, etc.  Note that this is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2$, there are essentially three different (kinds of) subspaces: Just the origin, a line through the origin, or the whole plane. In $\Bbb R^3$ there are four: The origin, a line (through the origin), a plane (containing the origin) or the whole space. In $\Bbb R^4$ there are five (you can probably guess which five those are). And so on.

Comment: What do you think the *definition* of dimension is (as in, the "dimension" of a subspace)?